# how can we get data from mongodb in one docker project and insert into mongodb of another project

Tags: mongodb, docker

I have data in mongodb in one project.I am integrating this project functionality to another project,so I want to get whole data from the project and insert into this integration project.so much like data migration.

Comment: Is it okay if you just need to clone the container volume from one to another? Any configuration will be kept the same as the old container.

Answer (score 0):

There is 2 parts to this.

First is the actual migration of date from 1 dB to another, u can use a any random tool to do that.

2nd is the docker networking part. So you can either get them to talk to each other by their ip, you can see them via docker inspect. However u need to manually do this everytime, the other is to use host.docker.internal, which means it will route it via your host pc, saving u having to find the up each time.